# Getting interface from Hierarchy of interfaces

Tags: c++, inheritance, casting

I have a hierarchy of interfaces as follows:

```
class interface1
{
public:
    virtual ~interface1() = 0;
}

class interface2 : public interface1
{
public:
    virtual ~interface2() = 0;
}
```

My data model has classes that can either be derived from Interface1 or interface2:

```
class cls1 : public interface1
{
}
class cls2 : public interface2
{
}
```

I want to write an overloaded function that works either on interface1 or interface2

```
void function1(interface1 * obj)
{
    // do something here
}
void function1(interface2 * obj)
{
    // do something here
}
```

Now I want to create object of both - cls1 and cls2, and invoke function1:

```
{
    .........
    cls1 *p1 = new cls1;
    cls2 *p2 = new cls2;

    function1(p1);
    function1(p2);        
    .........
}
```

My problem is that - in both cases, function1(interface1 * obj) is always invoked. I do not want to use if-else combined with dynamic_cast (that's the whole point of creating interface hierarchy).
Can anyone suggest me a way to invoke function1(interface2* obj) with an object of cls2?

Comment: On an unrelated note, your destructors seem to be missing the `virtual` keyword.

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem. With obvious fixes applied but otherwise exactly the same code, gcc uses the appropriate function [as expected](http://ideone.com/a4H0dm)(ideone.com)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're trying to do sounds awfully similar to virtual functions. Why not define `function1` as a member function of your class:

```
class interface1
{
public:
    virtual void function1()
    {
        // Do what you want to do when deriving from interface1
    }
}

class interface2 : public interface1
{
public:
    virtual void function1()
    {
        // Do what you want to do when deriving from interface2
    }
}
```

Comment: This was obvious solution for me, but it's not so simple. What if function1() and funtion2() are part of a different class, and have different implementations for cls1 and cls2? Good example is, Visitor pattern.

Answer (score 0):

People more knowledgeable than me told me that is was a bad idea to rely on the compiler to detect the return value you want from a class implicitly. That could cause no end of problems, as they are sometimes chosen differently than you expect.

So, in this case, I would use an explicit cast, like

```
function1( static_cast<interface1*>( p1 ));
function1( static_cast<interface2*>( p2 ));
```

I know it is not as compact, but if you look at your code a year from now it will make more sense.

Answer (score 0):

From a more high-level point-of-view than the other answers: What you are trying to accomplish is to dispatch a function call based on the type of the argument. C++ does not support this in general.

There are two options:

1. As @PaF wrote, you can make the function virtual.
2. If you really do not want to have the function as a class member, you can emulate so-called *double dispatch* (determining the function to call based on both the object it is called on as well as the type of the argument) by applying the visitor pattern. This way, you can call a function based on the type of the argument while avoiding the dynamic_cast.